# android browser location bar doesn't update for fragment change

Tags: android, browser, browser-history, android-browser

This seems crazy. I must be missing something. When setting location fragment in Android Browser (ICS, 4.0.3), the location bar fails to update to show the new fragment. Seems to fail equally whether setting `window.location`, `window.location.hash`, or a plain old `<a href="#foo">`. The browser does indeed navigate to the desired fragment, and on refresh, the location bar contains the fragment as expected. And the back button works! The only thing wrong is that the displayed address in the location bar should reflect the new location+fragment immediately, but it does not.

Good example can be seen at [Google Closure goog.History demo page](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/history1.html).

Comment: Will only occur in the the andriod native browser on.

Answer (score 0):

We noticed this too in Android 4.0.4.

Even worse is that at least on one Device (Galaxy Nexus) the hash navigation breaks if the url only contains a path e.g. `http://www.example.com/path/`. You can then navigate to fragment urls just fine, but **tapping the back button has no effect**.

The problem is fixed when a file is present in the url.

```
# will fail when using browser back button
www.example.com/path/

# will work although no fragment is shown
www.example.com/path/index.html
```